# How do I organize a multivariate linear model into matrices and vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm reading through [an SUU lecture on multivariate regression](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~maitra/stat501/lectures/MultivariateRegression.pdf), and I'm guessing some linear algebra knowledge is assumed. However, I have very little familiarity with linear algebra.

They start out with a function like this:

$$Y_j = \beta_0 +\beta_1z_{j1} +\beta_2z_{j2} +\cdots +\beta_rz_{jr} +\epsilon_j$$

and then, in the next slide:

> With $n$ independent observations, we can write one model for each sample unit or we can organize everything into vectors and matrices so that the model is now
>   $\mathbf{Y} =Z\boldsymbol{\beta}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$.

Comment: I actually attend ISU and have studied previously with that professor. If you plan on continuing further into the notes, you *need* to know linear algebra if you're going to be able to proceed. There are some very steep prerequisites (if you don't know linear algebra) if you want to be able to learn the material in that class.

Comment: I can give you a quick answer, but do note that by the time people have taken this class, they have already spent a whole semester looking at this material that you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As given in the notes, we have $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $Z$ is the design matrix, $\boldsymbol{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}^{r+1}$, and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. In matrix form, the multiple regression equation given above is written as
$$\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_n \\
y_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix} &{}={} &\begin{bmatrix}
1 & z_{11} & z_{12} & \cdots & z_{1r} \\
1 & z_{21} & z_{22} & \cdots & z_{2r} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & z_{(n-1)1} & z_{(n-1)2} & \cdots & z_{(n-1)r} \\
1 & z_{n1} & z_{n2} & \cdots & z_{nr} \\
\end{bmatrix}
&\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\vdots \\
\beta_r
\end{bmatrix} &{}+{} &\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_1 \\
\epsilon_2 \\
\vdots \\
\epsilon_n \\
\epsilon_{n+1}
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\[0.1ex]
\mathbf{Y} &{}={} &Z &\boldsymbol{\beta} &{}+{} &\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\text{.}
\end{array}$$
I leave it to you to see why this is. At the very least, I recommend that you learn how to multiply matrices.